# VSTO Outlook Add-In emails remains in outbox when I try to re-send

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I develop VSTO Outlook Add-In for Outlook, which is working with outlook items.

The porpoise of add-in - to analyze recipients and to find conversations.
It prevents Application_MailItemSend action during analysis and after it sends the email.

Sometimes emails stuck in outbox folder with "None" value in "Sent" column.
If I try to re-send this email

1. if my add-in is enabled the email remains in outbox.
2. if add-in is disabled the email sends correctly.

How I can fix this issue in Add-In side?

Answer (score 0):

Touching a message being submitted with Outlook UI or Outlook Object Model aborts the submission process. `Application.ItemSend` is your last chance to do anything with that message - after that, it is hands off: the only allowed operation is releasing your reference to that message.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I found the cause of stacking. My add-in also prevents CurrentExplorer_Event where it getting app.ActiveExplorer().Selection (selected item in current folder) and read property of selected item. These actions violated the integrity of the letter and Outlook mark it as touched.